# What powerplay activity is immediately profitable?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Most of the activities in Powerplay yield power points but don't generate a significant amount of money (sometimes 1,000 Cr per PP).

How can I earn at least 100,000 Cr while still helping my faction?

Comment: it doesn't seem like PowerPlay is a way to make money, rather than obliterate your funds. The bulletin board missions were overhauled as part of the update and now offer more money to fund your PowerPlay efforts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the best way to make 100,000 Cr quickly while helping your Power, is to find a trade route between systems your Power needs deliveries to/from, and combine the PowerPlay deliveries with trading.

I believe all of the powers have Preparation, Expansion and/or Control PowerPlay actions they ask of you that are basically deliveries. Some are between headquarters and other systems. Some are between a control system and a preparation or expansion target system. You need to read the description for your particular power to figure out where the deliveries need to start and end.

Figure out a few different PowerPlay delivery routes that will help your Power. Check out what kind of economies are at each station (or use one of the trading tools). You should be able to figure out some trading options that line up with PowerPlay deliveries. Fill your cargo or multi-purpose ship up with a mix of cargo and PowerPlay deliveries. Instead of spending your money on more PowerPlay things to deliver when you haven't reached the timeout to pick up more, just do runs of cargo until that timer resets.

---

If you stick with purely powerplay things, you need to get up in the ranks to really make money, and there's a delay 1-2 weeks before you start getting that salary. Rank 5 earns a 50,000,000 Cr a week salary, but requires 10,000 merits. Merits partially carry over from week to week, so once you get to rank 5 you may only need to earn ~3,500 merits a week to stay there... More reasonably, Rank 4 only takes 1,500 merits and earns 5,000,000 credits a week. 1,500 merits is just 100 interdiction kills of rival power npcs in a hostile system...

Comment: Note: If you pick up trade routes to go with your Power deliveries and you don't  first verify that the system you're helping Prepare is a good one for the Power to Prepare, you'll be the person everybody is complaining about in the forums as a "fifth columnist" acting against your Power's best interests.